# BTRFS: Multiple copies of metadata on different physical drives

Tags: btrfs, metadata

I have rather big btrfs volume assembled as a single drive using different physical size drives. The data is single, the metadata is raid1. Still all the (meta)data is within a single volume.

I understand that if one of the physical drives within this volume fails I may not be able to access the data on the remaining drives. I also understand that the metadata contains the information on the data distribution within the physical drives.

Is there a way to further improve the data safety by providing extra redundancy for metadata and this time on a separate physical drive that does not belong to this large volume? If yes, how to do this?

Volume0 - data(volume0,single), mdata(volume0,raid1)
Volume1 - mdata(volume0,raid1)

Comment: Have you tried `btrfs balance ...`?

Comment: I am aware of it but just can't make sense how to do this and not sure if this is possible at all. Before using the balance, I would need to add the new device and if I add it to the existing volume it will be a part of it. If to a separate volume how do I copy the meta data to this extra volume?

Comment: @agatek have you found an answer?